# Filter any rows that contain Inf

Tags: r

I am trying to debug and check why some rows on a data frame contain Inf values.

```
blah <- data.frame(
    x = 1:10,
    y = c(1:7,Inf,9:10),
    z = c(Inf, 2:10)
    )
```

Tried:

```
blah %>% filter_if(is.infinite)
Error in selected[[i]] <- eval_tidy(.p(column, ...)) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

Desired result is a new data frame with the rows that contain Inf values, in the case of blah, rows 1 and 8.

How can I filter a data frame to return all rows where any of them contain Inf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new `across` syntax, I think the most direct way would be

```
blah %>% filter(across(everything(), is.infinite) %>% purrr::reduce(`|`))
```

The `reduce` here checks if *any* of the columns are infinite rather than *all* of the columns. If you wanted the opposite selection, its a bit easier with just

```
blah %>% filter(across(everything(), is.finite))
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the code below works for you

```
subset(blah,is.infinite(rowMeans(blah)))
```

giving

```
  x   y   z
1 1   1 Inf
8 8 Inf   8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with tidyverse:

```
blah %>% rowwise %>% filter(any(is.infinite(c_across(where(is.numeric)))))
```

which produces:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      x     y     z
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   Inf
2     8   Inf     8
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This did indeed work for me but I went with Mr Flicks just because I found it slightly more readable

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` approach would be:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
blah %>% 
  filter(apply(., 1, function(row) any(is.infinite(row))))
```

Output:

```
  x   y   z
1 1   1 Inf
2 8 Inf   8
```

Comment: I think you want to avoid that `apply` if at all possible as it will slow down on big data as it loops every row, maybe `blah %>% filter_at(vars(names(blah)), any_vars(is.infinite(.)))` to use similar logic.

Comment: @thelatemail It is a great suggestion. I posted as an option for the OP question :)

Answer (score 1):

An option with `Reduce` and `lapply` in `base R`

```
blah[Reduce(`|`, lapply(blah, is.infinite)),]
#  x   y   z
#1 1   1 Inf
#8 8 Inf   8
```